# rxplot is not plotting

Tags: ros, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to plot some states of the pr2 robot. the command line is exactly

rxplot /r_arm_controller/

However, all I get is a plot screen that comes up with no data being plotted. Is there any remedy to this? Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31377/rxplot-is-not-plotting/) by [alexanderjyuen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2045/alexanderjyuen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-06**:
Are you sure messages are being published for that topic? What does `rostopic hz /r_arm_controller` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to give rxplot the name of the fields you wish to plot.  In the above, you are just giving the topic name.  See the rxplot documentation:

http://ros.org/wiki/rxplot

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1